# Does any country have Covid-19 death (or infection) statistics by occupation?

Tags: covid-19, risks, statistics, contributing-factors

I know this only marginally on-topic, but besides healthcare workers, I'd guess workers who meet a lot of people daily are also at high risk. There have been some reports in the US of [supermarket closures after worker deaths](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/24/business/walmart-coronavirus-colorado-death/index.html) but they seem to lack systematic statistics on that.

Are such statistics (deaths/infections) with Covid-19 by occupation available in some other countries?

Comment: All our 19 deaths are retirees

Answer (score 2):

The UK Biobank contains both information on [occupation](https://biobank.ctsu.ox.ac.uk/crystal/field.cgi?id=20024), as well as [SARS-Cov-2 test results](https://news.bugbank.uk/2020/04/interpreting-uk-biobank-covid-19-test.html), for each of its participants:

> UK Biobank is an international health resource enabling research into the genetic and lifestyle determinants of common diseases of middle and older age. It comprises 500,000 participants... In this study, we implemented rapid dynamic linkage, which allows us to provide a regular feed of new COVID-19 (SARS-CoV-2) test results to UK Biobank to facilitate rapid and urgent research into the epidemiological and human genetic risk factors for severe infection in the cohort.

- [Dynamic linkage of COVID-19 test results between Public Health England’s Second Generation Surveillance System and UK Biobank](https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.12091455) (2020) *

One could easily create a breakdown of disease rate by profession using this dataset, as in similar studies on other respiratory diseases e.g:

- [The occupations at increased risk of COPD in the UK Biobank Cohort](https://erj.ersjournals.com/content/50/suppl_61/PA417) (2017)

But note:

1. The age-demographic etc of the cohort may bias the types of profession present
2. This is UK specific

---

<sup>* Disclaimer: I have worked on this project.</sup>